# What is the difference between the GrideView.custom & GrideView.extent widget layout in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

What is the difference between the *`GridView.custom` & `GridView.extent`* widget layout in flutter?

**If you answer this question please attach the example code
and clear explanation.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`GridView.extent`**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Grid'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: GridView.extent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: width / 3,
          children: List.generate(
            20,
            (index) => Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('Widget : $index'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In `GridView.extent`, we use `maxCrossAxisExtent` to set the maximum space we want to give to each `children`. Here we are giving a `maxCrossAxisExtent: width / 3`, that means we are giving each children 1/3 of the width available.

**`GridView.custom`**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Grid'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: GridView.custom(
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
          childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('Widget $index'),
              );
            },
            childCount: 200,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In `GridView.custom`, we get option to use `SliverGridDelegate gridDelegate and SliverChildDelegate childrenDelegate`.

For `SliverGridDelegate` you can use :

- SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount - No. of children in the cross axis
- SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent - Max cross axis space for each children (Same that we re doing using `GridView.extent`)

For `SliverChildDelegate` you can use :

- SliverChildBuilderDelegate - Provides builder callback to construct the children
- SliverChildListDelegate - Provides option to make explicit list of children.

**Both of the above code generates the same output.`Grid.extent` is just a shorthand to create grid layout with fixed children size while we can do the same thing using `GridView.custom` as it is more flexible and you can do more things using it.**

[image]